# Cannot set the default library via Zend Server CLI tool

Tags: zend-server

I'm trying to deploy a library package via the "**zs-manage**" command-line, and it can be uploaded to the Zend server successfully, but cannot set as the default library. Here is the command I used:

```
zs-manage library-deploy PACKAGE_PATH -N WEBAPI_NAME -K WEBAPI_KEY
```

However, if I upload the library package in the Zend server management website, it will be set as default automatically. Also I find in the zend server, the "default" is set as a link to the library, I tried to re-link it to another library, but the management website still show the default library is the old one.

[Zend server CLI doc](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6.2/zend-server.htm#working_with_cli_tools.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I had a test to deploy the library by using "zs-manager", and create a symbolic link named "default" as the library I have deployed on the Linux server directly. The result is, even the default library shown in Zend management page is not the one I linked to, but the application will still use the library linked as "default" on the Linux server.